# Can we host a VB6.0 user control in WPF forms?

Tags: wpf

Can we host a VB6.0 user control in WPF forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB6 user controls are ActiveX

[Walkthrough: Hosting an ActiveX Control in Windows Presentation Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742735.aspx)

Comment: yea sure..i feel this link is very much usefull

Comment: hmm..but my concern is reliablity of code..the user control will maintain same behaviour like previous one?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, maybe not. .NET can handle COM/ActiveX controls so there should be a way to do this.

But you would include non-managed code to your project. Not only would this make your code a lot less reliable, it also would make the installation much more complex. In general, it's not worth the trouble.

Comment: i find the way..we can do it using form control library..but my concern is that ..is it a reliable way to do this?